# Установка шрифта Times New Roman в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Прописал комманду:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

Шрифты установились, но в ONLYOFFICE не появляются.

Помогите исправить ошибку.

Comment: https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/ru/server/linux/document/install-fonts.aspx

Comment: У меня нет файла documentserver-generate-allfonts.sh. в /user/bin/

Comment: теперь есть: https://www.google.com/search?q=documentserver-generate-allfonts.sh&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b

Comment: и сразу вам расскажу, как его поставить в /usr/bin/: делаете git clone (потом читаете ридми), но  скорее всего, всё сведётся к банальному ``install documentserver-generate-allfonts.sh /usr/bin/`` от рута.

Answer (score 1):

Решение намного проще. Нужно просто скачать шрифт, который вам нужен (формат .ttf)
Скачаный шрифт я переместил в папку /usr/share/fonts. Перезапустил ONLYOFFICE и шрифт появился.

Comment: Не надо в системные каталоги класть кастомную всячину — fdo специально разработала стандарты на иерархию домашнего дерева каталогов, ищите *~/.local*.